# Subversive SVN Connector installation fails in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

The installation of the Subversive SVN Connectors currently fails with Eclipse Oxygen.

*eclipse.log*

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature 4 0 2017-07-03 10:55:36.977
!MESSAGE SVN: 'SVN Decorator' operation finished with error
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature 4 0 2017-07-03 10:55:36.977
!MESSAGE SVN: 'SVN Decorator' operation finished with error: Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.UnreportableException: Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.
```

See also the bug report in the eclipse bugzilla https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=518033

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can manually install the Subversive SVN Connectors by adding the update site https://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site/ (check latest stable update site here: https://polarion.plm.automation.siemens.com/products/svn/subversive/download) and installing the necessary packages, e.g. for native 1.9.x in Eclipse x86:

- Subversive SVN Connectors
- Native JavaHL 1.9 Implementation
- JavaHL 1.9.3 Win32 Binaries

Comment: Does not work here.  Fresh install of Oxygen 4.7.0, fresh workspace. When trying to install the connector, the installation window just flashes and disappears. In the settings I still cannot select a connector.

Comment: Did you go through `Help` -> `Install New Software...`? There you need to select the update site you added (if you haven't added it so far, do it by pressing `Add...`) and afterwards the appropriate packages.

Comment: Using this procedure, I'm getting this error:

`An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
Error reading signed content.
Exception in opening zip file: <MY ECLIPSE FOLDER>\plugins\org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector_6.0.4.I20161211-1700.jar`

It seems that the jars are corrupted

Comment: Works great for me.

Comment: I also had the "error reading signed content" error. I checked the .jar and it was indeed only 1kb. I manually replaced it with the jar I downloaded from community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site/plugins/org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector_6.0.4.I20161211-1700.jar and re-did the installation. Then it worked.

Comment: Worked like a charm, many thanks! But... Why are the connectors not readily available after installing Subversive anyway?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, I had the same problem.
My environment is eclipse jee oxygen1.

I installed the subversive first.
And when the eclipse popup the install connectors dialog and I select the connector, eclipse doesn't install the connector.

In the preference -> SVN page, the connector combo box is empty.

I solved as belows.

1. install new software by
   http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site/
2. select Subversive SVN connectors, and SVNKit implementation both.
   The important is not only select Subversive SVN connectors, but also SVNKit implementation.
3. install and restart.

**[edited in 2018-06-29]**

As for eclipse photon, the svn connector problem seems to be resolved.

1. Just install svn plugin(subversive) through eclipse marketplace.
   (eclipse marketplace locates in "Help - Eclipse Marketplace")
2. set svn connector in the preference
   (window - preferences - team - SVN - SVN connector tab)

**[edited in 2023-01-26]**

Unfortunately, this website doesn't work anymore.
( http://community.polarion.com/ )

So, you would have to install subclipse not subversive.

Comment: Only the HTTP site does no longer work, the same URL with HTTPS works: `https://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/neon-site/`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.

Like lazlev answered, I tried to manually install the Subversive SVN Connectors by adding the update site https://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site/ in the "Install new software" window.

When I chose Subversive SVN Connectors and SVNKit packages, I got the following error as MscG mentionned:

An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase. session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTru‌​st, operand=, action=). Error reading signed content. Exception in opening zip file: \plugins\org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector_6.0.‌​4.I20161211-1700.jar

The only way I could work around this is by:

-Install SVN connector alone first. Restart Eclipse.

-Then go back to Install new software and install SVNKit alone. Restart Eclipse.

Comment: Edited [2023-Feb-04]
Thanks @magauthier for your suggestion. It helped me to get my eclipse project running with exact sequence as you described. Install one item at a time.

Answer (score 3):

I'm Using Spring Tool Suite 3.9.0 which is based on eclipse oxygen 4.7.0 and encountered the same problem.

From The Help / MarketPlace menu I installed "Subservive - SVN Team Provider 4.0.5"
Then I had to manually install the svn connector with the Help / Install new software menu. I used this URL : "http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site/" And choosed the SVNKIT 1.8.14 ( tried the 1.8.15 but it didn't worked ... )

As a result, I finally obtained a connector in the Preference/Team/SVN/SVN connector menu...

It worked better with the preceeding version of STS...

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the 64bit eclipse as the JavaHAL only exists in 32bit

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint.
I did exactly the same steps on ubuntu using **the url mentioned for both steps** (svn connector and svnkit): http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site/

It doesn't work with the latest version of SVNKit using svnkit url.

Answer (score 0):

For those who above workarounds didn't resolve their problems, upgrade Eclipse Oxygen 1 to **Eclipse Oxygen 3a**. Seems to work like a charm with *Subversive - SVN Team Provider 4.0.5*

Answer (score -1):

Reinstalling did the trick for me.
In eclipse go to help>Eclipse Marketplace search again for svn. click on installed. Update.